# Bootstrap-sass in Ruby on Rails 4 doesn't do anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-sass

I'm following [this](http://arubystory.blogspot.ca/2013/12/tutorial-creating-simple-todo.html) tutorial, and from the moment it tells me to integrate bootstrap I'm lost. I don't know anything about bootstrap, so I can't really troubleshoot it. Nothing happens, the formatting continues to look like standard HTML without any css styling at all.

This is my application.css.scss file:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
@import 'bootstrap';
```

This is my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

this is my view file (home.html.haml):

```
.container
  - if @tasks.empty?
    %span.text-warning There are no tasks!
  - else
    %table.table.table-hover.table-bordered
      %thead
        %tr
          %th Title
          %th Created at
          %th Completed
      %tbody
        - @tasks.each do |task|
          %tr
            %td
              %strong= task.title
            %td.text-info= task.created_at
            %td.text-success= task.completed
```

I know this is really specific, but since I don't know anything about bootstrap I don't know what to focus on as the problem. I'm running Rails 4.0.4, and the bootstrap-sass gemfile is 2.3.2.0

Comment: And its working because I overlooked an error in an unrelated piece of code that trickled down. My error. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a test Rails 4.0.4 app, renamed the `application.css` file to `application.css.scss` and added your

```
@import 'bootstrap';
```

line. By the way, I switched to the most recent gem version:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1.0'
```

And everything works fine.
Update your `Gemfile`, run `bundle update`, the restart the server and try again. It should work fine.